How to exclude empty tags exporting orders as XML file?
I am using PHP code in the plugin WP ALL EXPORT PRO to filter out specific orders from WooCommerce that contain relevant products with relevant details & options and then export them via XML / FTP to my fulfillment partner.
The values for details & options are different for each product. Therefore I need a code snippet to generally exclude empty tags when exporting in the XML file (Concerning the pink marked area in overview below).

USED CURRENT PHP CODE. THE SECTION //add options to the output IS TO BE CONSIDERED
<?php
    function my_get_order_items( $order_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( absint($order_id) ); // Get the WC_Order object
    
        if ( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
            return false; // Exit if not an order
        }
        $order_details = ""; // Initialize variable as string to store order details
    
        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            if ( ! ( strpos($item->get_name(), 'KERAMIKTASSE') !== false
            || strpos($item->get_name(), 'BAUMWOLLTASCHE') !== false
            || strpos($item->get_name(), 'SWEATSHIRT') !== false
            || strpos($item->get_name(), 'HOODIE') !== false
            || strpos($item->get_name(), 'T-SHIRT') !== false ) ) { 
                continue; 
            }
            $product    = $item->get_product(); // Get the product object
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get the product object
    
            $order_details .= "**LT**item**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**ID**GT**" . $product->get_sku() . "**LT**/ID**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**produktname**GT**" . $item->get_name() . "**LT**/produktname**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**amount**GT**" . $item->get_quantity() . "**LT**/amount**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**upload**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'upload', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/upload**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**size**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'size', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/size**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**groesse**GT**" . $product->get_attribute('pa_groesse')  . "**LT**/groesse**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**material**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'material', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/material**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**print**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'print', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/print**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**variante**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'variante', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/variante**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**category**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'category', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/category**GT**";
    
            //add options to the output
            $order_details .= "**LT**Options**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'groupid_115', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_115', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'groupid_117', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_117', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'groupid_118', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_118', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**/Options**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**/item**GT**";
        }
        return $order_details;
    }
?>


What about if(get_field( 'groupid_115', $product_id )) { } ?

Could you explain this in more detail? Unfortunately I am an absolute beginner...

The condition will check if there is any value if(get_field( 'groupid_115', $product_id )) {             $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'groupid_115', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_115', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**"; }if there is no value will skip it.


Check if each field has content before adding it to the
$order_details string.
Only add non-empty fields to the XML string.

function my_get_order_items($order_id)
{

    $order = wc_get_order(absint($order_id)); // Get the WC_Order object
    
    if (!is_a($order, 'WC_Order')) {
        return false; // Exit if not an order
    }
    
    $order_details = ""; // Initialize variable as string to store order details
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {

        if (!(strpos($item->get_name(), 'KERAMIKTASSE') !== false
            || strpos($item->get_name(), 'BAUMWOLLTASCHE') !== false
            || strpos($item->get_name(), 'SWEATSHIRT') !== false
            || strpos($item->get_name(), 'HOODIE') !== false
            || strpos($item->get_name(), 'T-SHIRT') !== false)) { 
            continue; 
        }
        
        $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the product object
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get the product ID

        $order_details .= "**LT**item**GT**";
        
        // Conditionally add each field only if it's not empty
        if ($sku = $product->get_sku()) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**ID**GT**" . $sku . "**LT**/ID**GT**";
        }
        
        if ($name = $item->get_name()) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**produktname**GT**" . $name . "**LT**/produktname**GT**";
        }

        if ($quantity = $item->get_quantity()) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**amount**GT**" . $quantity . "**LT**/amount**GT**";
        }
        
        if ($upload = maybe_serialize(get_field('upload', $product_id))) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**upload**GT**" . $upload . "**LT**/upload**GT**";
        }

        if ($size = maybe_serialize(get_field('size', $product_id))) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**size**GT**" . $size . "**LT**/size**GT**";
        }

        if ($groesse = $product->get_attribute('pa_groesse')) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**groesse**GT**" . $groesse . "**LT**/groesse**GT**";
        }

        if ($material = maybe_serialize(get_field('material', $product_id))) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**material**GT**" . $material . "**LT**/material**GT**";
        }

        if ($print = maybe_serialize(get_field('print', $product_id))) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**print**GT**" . $print . "**LT**/print**GT**";
        }

        if ($variante = maybe_serialize(get_field('variante', $product_id))) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**variante**GT**" . $variante . "**LT**/variante**GT**";
        }

        if ($category = maybe_serialize(get_field('category', $product_id))) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**category**GT**" . $category . "**LT**/category**GT**";
        }
        
        // Add options conditionally
        $order_details .= "**LT**Options**GT**";
        
        if ($groupid_115 = maybe_serialize(get_field('groupid_115', $product_id))) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . $groupid_115 . "**LT**/ID**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize(get_field('value_115', $product_id)) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        }
        
        if ($groupid_117 = maybe_serialize(get_field('groupid_117', $product_id))) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . $groupid_117 . "**LT**/ID**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize(get_field('value_117', $product_id)) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        }
        
        if ($groupid_118 = maybe_serialize(get_field('groupid_118', $product_id))) {
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . $groupid_118 . "**LT**/ID**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize(get_field('value_118', $product_id)) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        }
        
        $order_details .= "**LT**/Options**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**/item**GT**";
    }
    

    return $order_details;

}


Each field is only added if it contains data (i.e., it’s not empty). This prevents empty XML tags from being included in the exported XML.
Each option group (e.g., groupid_115, groupid_117, groupid_118) is only added if it has content.
This approach ensures only non-empty tags are included in the final XML output.
